# Method of variation of parameter

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals, differential-operators

By method of variation of parameters find the PI of the differential equation 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=4e^{2x}$$
I have learned how to do the find out the PI of second order differential equation. But, here is first order. I can't find any solution of this. Please help me.
$$\text{I tried to use the Wronskian method like:}$$
$$Let, y=e^{mx}\\
\implies Dy=me^{mx}$$
$$\text{Then, the auxiliary equation is:}\\
m+2=0\\
\implies m=-2$$
$$Then, C.F.=c_1e^{mx}$$
$$P.I. y_p= u(x)e^{mx}$$
Then, there we had to find wronskian. But, I can't get it how to find that...

Comment: Please show your work, if you're able to do for the second order then what's wrong with first order ?

Comment: looking at the right side, you could use the Ansatz $y=Ae^{2x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the Wronskian here it's a first order DE
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=4e^{2x}$$
Solve the homogeneous equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=0$$
$$\ln y =-2\int dx=-2x+c$$
$$y=ce^{-2x}$$
Variation of parameter needs
$$y=c(x)e^{-2x}$$
$$y'=c'(x)e^{-2x}-2e^{-2x}c(x)$$
Plug this in the differential equation and solve for $c(x)$.
$$y'+2y=4e^{2x}$$
$$c'(x)e^{-2x}-2e^{-2x}c(x)+2c(x)e^{-2x}=4e^{2x}$$
Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: You 're welcome @AnkitaPal

Answer (score 2):

Consider a general scalar dynamical system where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ $$\dot{x}(t)=ax(t)+bu(t) \implies \dot{x}(t)-ax(t)=u(t)$$
Now multiply both sides by $e^{-at}$, you get 
$$e^{-at} \left( \dot{x}(t)-ax(t)\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}e^{-at}x(t)=e^{-at}bu(t)$$Now integrating this between $0$ to $t$ gives you 
$$x(t)=e^{at}x(0)+e^{at}\int_0^t e^{-as}b u(s)\mathrm{d}s$$
Where the first term is the response due to initial condition $x(0)$ and the second term is the forced response due to the input $u(t)$

Comment: Thanks for the clue